# can't add gameobject to a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, 3d

I downloaded a script for my level's menu but when I tried it the script I couldn't assign my scrollbar to the script. I tried to copy the script and paste it again and make a new script but it didn't work. how can I fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class swipe_menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject scrollbar;
    private float scrollpos = 0;
    float[] pos;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        pos = new float[transform.childCount];
        float distance = 1f / (pos.Length - 1f);
        for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
        {
            pos[i] = distance * i;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            scrollpos = scrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
            {
                if (scrollpos < pos[i] + (distance / 2) && scrollpos > pos[i] - (distance / 2))
                {
                    scrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value = Mathf.Lerp(scrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value, pos[i], 0.1f);
                }
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
        {
            if (scrollpos < pos[i] + (distance / 2) && scrollpos > pos[i] - (distance / 2))
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Current Selected Level" + i);
                transform.GetChild(i).localScale = Vector2.Lerp(transform.GetChild(i).localScale, new Vector2(1.2f, 1.2f), 0.1f);
                for (int j = 0; j < pos.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                        transform.GetChild(j).localScale = Vector2.Lerp(transform.GetChild(j).localScale, new Vector2(0.8f, 0.8f), 0.1f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any compile errors in editor? Look at the console for any red that can't be cleared (that's my guess). If not make sure you wait for unity to compile before trying to add the component and finally close and relaunch unity if its still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Scrollbar as a `GameObject` and not as a `Scrollbar`, try using is like with the correct variable and it will work.

There are not many places to find how to use the Scrollbar, the best i could find is
https://forum.unity.com/threads/access-scrollbar-value-not-possible-through-code.283486/

Comment: actually I tried but when I tried it again it worked. thanks for ur help. but there is a problem my button image disappeared.

Comment: @Mohamad Do you want to send me more information (maybe Git link) so I can take a better look?

Comment: thx for helping me I fixed it by removing and adding the script again to my game object.